# How do I force a tomcat web application reload the trust store after I update it

Tags: java, tomcat, truststore

I have the following problem.
My tomcat 5.5 based web application is using a trust store to verify SSL connections.
The application allows the user to add or remove CA certificates to be used in the verification process.
However, adding or removing certificates from the trust store doesn't change a thing. The application 'recognizes' only the certificates that were in the trust store when tomcat started. For it to recognize the new set of certificates, I need to restart tomcat.

This is not a valid solution, however.
What I do need is a code based solution.
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about writing a Custom Classloader that loads in the trust store ONLY for this webapp. You could unload the classloader when you need to refresh the contents and reload it ?